# Highlight Google search queries in Google Chrome

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

Is there a way to have searched queries in Google Search Engine in bold in Google Chrome, inside the results' content (automatically, without having to ctrl+f for them every time)?

I've tried to do it with an extension, but I didn't see anything highlighted, as I'm used to in Firefox.

**Edit:**

I don't have Firefox installed, but this is what it would look like (on Chrome the searched query isn't shown in bold):

### Firefox

[image: Firefox]

### Chrome

This is what I'm getting on Google Chrome:
[image: Google Chrome]

Comment: Can you share an example of what you see on Firefox? I see that the search term is bold both on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: You mean in the website description/quote or in the website title?

Comment: @arieljannai Both if possible as you can see in the picture below (2nd, 3rd and 4th results).

Comment: Perhaps it's the font that Chrome is using. My search terms are bolded as you expect. (Chrome 65, Win7)

Comment: Besides the font, an extension could be causing the issue.

Comment: You might be right, when I visualize the source-code I see the query between `em` html tags. This issue is occuring both at the office (Win10) and on my laptop (Win8). I don't think it's caused by an extension; I only have adblock installed and deactivating it doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The query is bold in the exact same way. Both on Firefox and Chrome.

The screenshot you shared belongs to an old version of Firefox (from around 2012).

**Today's behavior:**
Only the relevant text in the sites description/content is bold.

[image]

I couldn't find any extension that will format the titles in bold or highlight them (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) - if you have minimal knowledge in programming, I believe you could write your own extension to do that.

Comment: For me on Chrome even the searched query in the content of the results  (not just the title) doesn't appear in the bold, quite strange.

Comment: Which version do you use? You can check that by accessing `chrome://version`

Comment: Chrome 66 on Windows 10.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of a search results page on Chrome?